# How do you pass two arguments to webpack?

Tags: gulp, webpack

I'm piping to webpack and need to pass a configuration file and `devtool` parameter.  I tried a few variations of dual param passing none worked.

```
//This works
gulp.task('js', function() {
  gulp.src(config.paths.mainJs)
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.dev.js')
            //how do we sourcemap this?
            //devtool: "source-map"
         ))

//This fails
gulp.task('js', function() {
  gulp.src(config.paths.mainJs)
    .pipe(webpack({ 
             configuration: require('./webpack.config.dev.js'),
             devtool: "source-map"
         }))
```

I found the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver) for configuration.  It did not provide any examples of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `./webpack.config.dev.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
   // configuration
};
```

your require statement returns an ordinary JavaScript object, so you can just overwrite the `devtool` prop:

```
var extend = require('extend');

gulp.task('js', function() {
  var config = extend({}, require('./webpack.config.dev.js'), {
    devtool: "source-map",
  });
  gulp.src(config.paths.mainJs)
    .pipe(webpack(config))
  ...
});
```

I used the [`extend`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extend) npm package to combine the configs into a new object, but you can use something else if you like. You could also leave out the `extend` altogether and just set the `devtool` property like this:

```
var config = require('./webpack.config.dev.js');
config.devtool = "source-map";
```

But remember that nodejs caches required files, so if you require `webpack.config.dev.js` from somewhere else in your Gulpfile.js afterwards, it will have the `devtool` property already set to `"source-map"`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a method of passing arguments as detailed in this post.

You can pass args via npm using the package.json scripts section.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "babel": "babel",
    "webpack-quizMaker": "set arg=quizMaker&&webpack",
    "webpack-quiz": "set arg=quiz&&webpack"
  },
```

for more detailed information see the below link.

https://www.hipstercode.com/blog/27/